# Spring is too long at returning cached instance of singleton bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here's my log message.

```
09:24:21.633 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0'
09:24:21.633 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#32311ede'
09:24:21.637 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#32311ede'
09:24:21.637 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
09:24:21.638 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
09:24:21.638 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
09:24:21.638 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
09:24:21.640 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
09:24:21.643 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'

09:24:21.643 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
09:24:21.643 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
09:24:21.643 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
09:24:21.644 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
09:24:21.647 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
09:24:21.647 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
09:24:21.648 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
09:24:21.648 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0'
09:24:21.648 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0'
09:24:21.652 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
09:24:21.700 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'jasyptPasswordEncryption
09:24:21.702 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'tenantDetailsService'
```

Here's my Configuration for Spring Security

and the said classes

```
@Service
public class TenantDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepo userAccountRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserAccount account = userAccountRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if(account != null){
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(account.getRole()));
            return new TenantUserDetails(account.getUsername(),
                    account.getPassword(),authorities,account.getTenantCode());
        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad Credentials");
        }
    }
}
```

And the jasypt password encryption service

```
@Service
public class JasyptPasswordEncryptionService implements PasswordEncryptionService,PasswordEncoder{

    private StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword,String  encodedPassword) {
        try{
            return passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
        }catch (EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException encryptionOperationNotPossibleException){
            return  false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was It already took me 30 mins and the build was still wasn't finish and I am stuck on that two lines. However, I changed my authentication manager to springs default authentication manager and it worked

Have I configured my authentication manager wrong?

**EDIT**
My existing configurations works on my windows machine, however on an ubuntu 14.04 it does not

Comment: Can you please specify, what exactly your problem is? Is it the 0.05 seconds between the eagerly caching and the first returning of the cached instance? Are you sure, that there is nothing else between that two commands which could take some time? Also, every DEBUG log message takes time, so this is not representative.

Comment: If a build is hanging, you can create a thread dump and lookup the thread which is blocking the build to inspect the stacktrace.

Comment: @dunni how do I perform the thread dump while the build is ongoing?

Comment: Execute `jstack -l JAVA_PID > jstack.out` and replace JAVA_PID with the process id of your build (you can find jstack in the bin folder of your JDK).

Comment: @dunni already did a thread dump. What's next? I have no idea what/ how will I read this

Comment: I've got the same problem as you and activated `trace=true` and realize it's stucked in a loop. Trying to find out what is happening.